# Selenium for Python: How to enter an array of strings again & again in the same textbox in the same webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I want to automate searching for an array of strings in Google using Python for Selenium.

Here's a test program I wrote using numbers as search query:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
number = input('Enter a number: ')
for number in range(number,10):
    el = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    el.send_keys(number)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    el.submit()
```

For `number=2`: I got the output as a search for `"23456789"`

But my desired output is searches separately for 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Any ideas on how I can do this? I'm using PyDev in Eclipse as my editor.

So I slowed the program down using time.sleep

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
number = input('Enter a number: ')
for number in range(number,10):
    el = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    el.send_keys(number)
    time.sleep(10)
    el.submit()
```

I found that all the numbers from 2 to 10 are being typed before the submit() function is executed. I want to execute the submit() function before the loop for 3 is executed.

Comment: Could you show (at least some of) the code that follows this, where you use the resulting loaded search page?

Comment: This is the whole of the program. I just submit & get the search results in the browser. That's about it for now.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output, then. Google search only shows one search per page. Do you want to open multiple browser windows? Or pause between searches? Or...?

Comment: From the code I provided, my desired output is first to search for 2(first query) then in the same page search for 3(second query) and so on till 10. Hope you get it.

Comment: thanks, that does make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
number = input('Enter a number: ')
for n in range(number,10):
    driver.get("http://google.com")
    el = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    el.send_keys(n)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_name("btnG").click()
    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that everytime you send new keys it will get appended to the textfield. That means it will make the searches for:

- 2
- 23
- 234
- 2345
- 23456
- 234567
- 2345678
- 23456789

All you need to do to prevent this is clear the element before you send new keys to it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
number = input('Enter a number: ')
for number in range(number,10):
    el = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    el.clear()
    el.send_keys(number)
    time.sleep(10)
    el.submit()
```

Also it is highly suggested to use explicit waits instead of implicit waits as this will have a big impact on the execution time.